# cannot read value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to post data to a webpage I have (page3.php). However, when I do `$test=$_POST['radio_second'];` on this page, there is no data in the test variable.

Can anyone figure it out? Many thanks.

```
<p>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="radio1_0">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_0" value="1" />

        <label for="radio1_1">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_1" value="2" />

        <label for="radio1_2">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_2" value="3" checked/>

        <label for="radio1_3">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_3" value="4" />

        <label for="radio1_4">5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_4" value="5" />
    </p>
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
<a href="page1.php"  data-inline="true" data-theme="a"  data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide" style="height:53px;width:150px">Prev</a>
<a href="page3.php"  data-inline="true" data-theme="a"  data-role="button" data-transition="slide" style="height:53px;width:150px">Next</a>
```

Comment: This markup is incomplete. Where are the extraneous `fieldset`, `div`, and anchor tags coming from? Please edit the rest of your markup into this question so that anyone who comes through here later can benefit from this question.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are not submiting your FORM to page3.php. A element in form is just opening page3.php without submiting form to it.  You need to replace that A element with <input type="submit" value="Next"> and place it before </form>, and add attribute action="page3.php" to FORM element. Alternatively you could use Javascript to trigger form submit when user clicks on link.

```
 <p>
      <form method="post" action="post3.php">
        <label for="radio1_0">1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_0" value="1" />
        <label for="radio1_1">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_1" value="2" />
     <label for="radio1_2">3</label>
         <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_2" value="3" checked/>
        <label for="radio1_3">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_3" value="4" />
     <label for="radio1_4">5</label>
         <input type="radio" name="radio_second" id="radio1_4" value="5" />

     <a href="page1.php"  data-inline="true" data-theme="a"  data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide" style="height:53px;width:150px">Prev</a>
     <input type="submit"  data-inline="true" data-theme="a"  data-role="button" data-transition="slide" style="height:53px;width:150px" value="Next" />

    </form>
   </p>
```

Comment: can you link me how to use Javascript to trigger form?